How to repair deep holes on external corner in old plaster wall
I’m removing an old tile backsplash in my kitchen (1910s apartment building) and a large amount of plaster broke off around one external corner:

more pictures
The horizontal plane on the right is a deep window ledge made out of what I think is mdf?
I was hoping to get away with just skimming over most of the formerly-tiled areas. I will be putting up an acrylic backsplash in this area so it’s not like I’ve got something heavy the wall needs to support.
However the deepest bits of this section are 6-7mm deep, and the corner beading just… stops part way down. There’s even what looks like a chunk of polystyrene in there.
The current plan for the backsplash is that it would finish 3/4 up this section– but I could easily tweak that measurement so the backsplash covers it all.
How would you recommend I tackle this repair? I’m very much a beginner at plastering so I’d appreciate you explaining it in simpler terms.

Remove all the loose old plaster, and wash off all of the dust. Apply new plaster in thin layers, 3 to 4mm each, and let each layer harden before applying the next one. When you have a flat surface with no more than 3mm between the lowest and highest points, do one last uniform coat. When it dries, do a rough sanding with a 80 or 120-grit sandpaper. Done.

+1 for going with multiple layers.

If the big hole is going to be covered it doesn't have to be pretty.
Just fill with drywall compound after removing the loose debris and dust. Then what you use is dependant on how fast you want to complete the job.
If time is no issue, fill with all purpose drywall compound. IT will shrink and crack and take maybe 2 days to dry.  Then come back and skim a final coat. When dry lightly sand (I like 100 grit or the drywall sanding screens).
                              OR

Use quick dry compound or (Hot mud) 10 or 20 min dry time will give enough time to work.   Fill the hole. Wait for it to dry.  Sand lightly and skim. You can prime and paint in another hour.
Since the area is around a window, even though you plan to cover with a backsplash, I may paint the bottom 4 inches or 100mm  with a waterproofing paint to keep any    condensation from wicking into the wall.
